# "export 'resize' was not found in '@engineers/graphics/index'

Tags: typescript, webpack, ts-loader

I got `"export 'resize' was not found in '@engineers/graphics'`

**graphics.ts**

https://github.com/eng-dibo/ngx/blob/master/packages/graphics/index.ts#L33

```
export type Img = string | Buffer | Sharp;
export type Size = number | string | null;
/**
 * [resize description]
 * @method resize
 * @param  {Img} img     file path or image buffer;
 * @param  {Size | Size[]} size    width or [width, height] or 'width,height', if size=null just convert img type
 * @param  {[type]} options [description]
 * @return Promise<info>
 *
 * todo:
 *  - rename size to dimensions
 *  - convert(img) = resize(img,size=null,{output=type})
 */
export function resize(
  img: Img,
  size: Size | Size[],
  options: ResizeOptions = {}
): Promise<any> {}
```

**in other file:**

https://github.com/eng-dibo/ngx/blob/master/projects/cms/server/api/v1.ts#L12

```
import { resize } from "@engineers/graphics/index";
```

Answer (score 0):

solved by fixing `package.json/name` field.
for some reason (I don't know why) the package name of this package is identical to another package in the same folder, so `require('path/to/graphic/package')` loads the other package, even it require it by path not by name like `require('package-name')`